# How do I deal with abusive parents?

Tags: parents, pre-teen

I'm only 13, and since I came back from Mexico (since 4 years) they have been abusive for 5 years. At first, it was all fine but then like 1 week later they became abusive. My parents are abusive my dad is always pulling my hair for something bad that I didn't even do. If my siblings do something bad, they blame it on me. I just can't handle them, sometimes I feel like it's time to run away.

Update:
My babysitter already knows about this and she's trying to help me.

Comment: Where are you living now? Can you talk to a teacher about what is happening? At your age running away is **very** dangerous: there are things out there that are far worse than what is happening to you now.

Comment: @PaulJohnson Yeah, and there are also things extremely dangerous about staying with abusive parents. Contrary to popular belief, a child will not get instantly kidnapped and murdered as soon as they are outside alone.

Comment: @forest The OP describes physical and psychological abuse which is certainly a concern but does not present immediate risk of death or serious injury.  You are correct that a 13 year old is not in immediate danger the instant they step out of the door, but sleeping rough and begging at that age *will* attract predators. Meanwhile any authorities the OP contacts for help after running away are likely to return them to their parents.

Comment: @PaulJohnson It _will_? Statistically that is not so. In fact, a child is overwhelmingly more likely to be seriously hurt by abusive parents (even parents whose abuses are currently "mild") than by a stranger. It's true that there are better alternatives than running away, but running away is not necessarily _more_ dangerous than staying at home. The _overwhelming_ majority of predators or otherwise abusive individuals get access to a child through abusive parents. It's extremely uncommon for them to be total strangers.

Comment: @forest The vast majority of children are not sleeping rough. The OPs best course is to get their countries child protection services involved.

Comment: @PaulJohnson Yes you're right. My point only was that staying is not necessarily better than leaving, not that there are not better options (like seeking help).

Comment: If you run away, you will probably be forced to return home and may have to deal with exacerbated abuse. Help through another adult is more likely to be recognised as legitimate and taken seriously in stead of taking actions into your own hands.

Answer (score 6):

I have some experience in this type of situation. The best thing to do is to talk to an adult who is **NOT** abusive towards you such as a guidance counselor. When talking to them, make sure to explain the full situation that you have and let them help you with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

SoyokoAnis has a good answer, However let me add something to that. You should never EVER act aggressive towards them, or it will just give them a real reason to do the things they do. If you have access to a phone and its really bad, I would call authorities and tell them what your going through, I would also get video proof of them doing it to you so you have evidence.